# Solr gives too many irrelevant results

Tags: solr, faceted-search

I have a tagging system and tags are like this:

```
italian kitchen
chinese kitchen
japanese kitchen
russian kitchen
vegeterian kitchen
```

When I query italian kitchen, I don't get the italian kitchen on top. I get russian and japanese all the time and other irrelevant results. In Solr schema, my tags field's type is string. I have no idea why this is happening. Can you share your ideas with me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The field type of "string" means your fields aren't getting tokenized. So each field has a single token -- the entire string passed in. So unless there's an exact phrase query match on the entire field, no result will be more relevant than any other,

You probably want to use the type "text" in the default schema, this will break up the field into tokens. IE instead of "Italian kitchen" you'll have both "Italian" and "kitchen" terms indexed in the field.

Comment: <field name="cat" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true"/> this is the field, when I search for italian kitchen, I get chinese kitchen on top, I think it breaks the words and gives me results like that. How can I get the exact result ?

Comment: Did you try a phrase query "italian kitchen". Its important for your query analysis to match your indexing analysis. The query itself is likely getting chopped up into tokens while the query is not. Remember in this setup, solr is looking for exact matches. The token "italian" matches exactly to "italian kitchen" just as well as it matches exactly "chinese kitchen". If you tokenized "italian kitchen" into "italian" and "kitchen" then "italian" would exact-match match the token "italian" and this result would be more relevant.

Comment: so I should change the cat field type to text from string ?

Comment: changed to text_general now, and no difference. I want it to be like mysql's field search but does not work, I am going to kill myself now

Comment: @user1794257 did you reindex everything?

Comment: I reindexed and it works like a charm, god bless you :) I hope you make lots of money and be a millionaire and live more than 100 years :)

Comment: If you indexed "italian kitchen" in the string field and query q=your_field:"italian kitchen" on this field, it should work though

Comment: @BobYoplait string field do not work I got irrelevant results

Comment: What do you index in the String field ? What is your query ?

Answer (score 1):

You really want to read through [the section on tokenizers](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/AnalyzersTokenizersTokenFilters), at least the first two sections. And then, if you are in Solr 4, go to Admin interface and try the Analysis screen under your core's section. That allows you to put your text in with your type (cat) and see what it actually breaks down to.

Now, it sounds to me like you want that "Italian Kitchen" to be a facet category as well as searchable. That's a double challenge because the facet values come from tokens produced, so you do want that as a string. In which case, my suggestion is to keep **cat** field as a string field and do copyField into **cat_text** which has a tokenized type (look in example's schema) and use eDismax to search across multiple fields including **cat_text**.

Comment: I am just a newbie and all I want, is to have exact results, I have no idea what are those :) what should I do to not get irrelevant results ? thank you for your answer

Answer (score 0):

make sure you do:

q=your_field:"italian kitchen"

and not

q=your_field:italian kitchen